# How to pass <select> html data in bootstrap modal to jquery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the selected value from this  tag that is located in a **modal**:

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-8'>
<form class='form-inline'>
<select class='form-control' name='sel1' id='sel1'>
      <option>1.00</option>
      <option>1.25</option>
      <option>1.50</option>
      <option>1.75</option>
      <option>2.00</option>
      <option>2.25</option>
      <option>2.50</option>
      <option>2.75</option>
      <option>3.00</option>
      <option>5.00</option>
      <option>INC</option>
      <option>DRP</option>
      <option>WDRW</option>
</select>

</div>
<div class='col-md-4' align='right'>
<input style='display: block; width: 100%;' type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Enter Grade' onclick='enterGrade($offeringno)'' />
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
function enterGrade(offering) {
  var enteredgrade = $("#myModal3 #sel1").val();
  var gradeoffering = offering;
  alertify.confirm("Enter grade?", function (e)
  { if (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "action.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : {
            gradeofferingPost : gradeoffering,
            enteredgrade1: enteredgrade
        },
        success : function(data) {
          alertify.alert(data);
          show_test();
        }});
      $('#myModal3').modal('toggle');
  } else {
      txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
  } });
}
```

What is the correct syntax to get the selected option from the `sel1` select (that is inside a **modal**) to the javascript function?

Comment: No reason `$("#myModal3 #sel1").val()` shouldn't work if the modal itself is   `$("#myModal3")` and you aren't repeating ID's anywhere. What is actually being returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access value of element that does not have a value. What you are looking for is `.text()`. If you want to get currently selected `text` of the `option` you should replace this:

```
var enteredgrade = $("#myModal3 #sel1").val();
```

with this:

```
var enteredgrade = $('#sel1 :selected').text();
```

If you are interested in `.val()` then you must replace

```
<option>1.00</option>
<option>1.25</option>
...
```

with this:

```
<option value="1.00">1.00</option>
<option value="1.25">1.25</option>
...
```

Comment: @charlietfl There is no value in option field. He should use `text()`

Comment: Will default to selected option text if no value attribute set in option tags ... https://jsfiddle.net/n0bz8yma/ Your statement is inaccurate

Comment: In fact this whole answer is full of inaccuracies to be honest

Comment: @charlietfl Should i remove it?

Comment: That's up to you...just pointing out some fundamental misconceptions being presented

Comment: @charlietfl Edit the answer according to you.

Comment: Can validate what I am telling you here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option Read the part about `value`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127970/discussion-between-aniket-sahrawat-and-charlietfl).